# Updating Images Loading in For Loop with GCD Thread - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following For loop which iterates through an NSMutableArray and calls the setImage method :

```
//Code to iterate through pictures and create ImageView class for each one.
for (int i =0; i<=[pictureThumbnailArray count]-1; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Thumbnail count is %d", [pictureThumbnailArray count]);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
    [self setImage:[pictureThumbnailArray objectAtIndex:i]:i];
                   });
}
```

The setImage method sets various parameters on the picture and then finally adds it to the subview on the main thread :

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self.view addSubview:onePicture];
        });
```

The problem is that the images appear on the screen randomly, rather than loading in order one by one. Can any suggest how I can improve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [global background queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_global_queue) is concurrent, not serial, meaning that it doesn't guarantee ordering. You can create a custom serial queue that does:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
```

and use that in your `dispatch_async`.